# Create issue API for jira giving 404 from postman

Tags: postman, jira-rest-api

I am trying to call jira rest API from postman for creating a issue
Follwing is my curl from postman

```
     url --location --request POST 'https ://mydomain.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue' \
        --header 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXX' \
        --header 'Accept: application/json' \
        --data-raw '{
            "fields": {
                "project": {
                    "id": "12019"
                 },
                 "issuetype": {
                     "id": "10002"
                 },
                 "customfield_12404" : {
                     "id": "12444"
                 },
                 "customfield_12394" : {
                     "id": "12421"
                 },
                 "summary": "Test of rest API",
                 "customfield_12391" : 1,
                 "customfield_11143": "test"
                 }
            }'
```

I am getting bad request in response

```
<body>
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
```

I am not sure what is wrong in this. I tried searching on this but did not get proper solution for my issue  Can anyone help me on this ?
Thanks

Comment: It might be from copying the text in, but there is a space after the https and the colon :.

Comment: ye that was while copying the text